# Excel Hyperlink formula doesn't work when concatenated with string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to mix-in hyperlinks with text.

This works fine:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/")
```

But this gives me an error.  I have seen both "Cannot open the specified file" and "The address of this site is not valid.  Check the address and try again" in different workbooks:

```
="navigate here: " & HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/")
```

I was expecting it to look something like this:

---

navigate here: http://www.google.com

---

What am I missing?  Perhaps it can't be done?  I need this to be in a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

This method would, unfortunately, make the entire cell clickable (hence, not just the link itself).

In the cell that contains your `HYPERLINK()`, right-click and select **Format Cells**  > **Number Tab** > **Custom**.

Enter this into the "Type" box:

```
"Navigate Here: "@
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/","Navagate here:  http://www.google.com")
```

[image]

Basically embedding the text in the "friendly name".